# Парсинг и запись большого CSV

Tags: php, парсер, csv

Задача следующая - имеется большой CSV-файл, откуда берётся - не известно, но подозреваю, что выгрузка из 1с, и скормить его в sql-базу, далее выводить из него данные плагином WP.
На текущий момент его размер чуть больше 2гб.

Сам файл разобрать не проблема, проблема встаёт в том, что стандартными средствами PHP это всё происходит а) долго, б) жрёт много памяти.
Суммарно там чуть больше 3 миллионов строк.

Собственно, хотелось бы получить советов, как это дело лучше оптимизировать, что бы в один момент не уронить сайт на неопределенное время?

Comment: Так может из sql это делать? База какая? И ещё костыльный вариант: сконвертировать csv в sql-запросы.

Comment: многие движки баз данных умеют подгружать данные с cvs файла напрямую. Вряд ли на php сделаете быстрее. вот MySql так умеет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-do-i-import-csv-file-into-a-mysql-table

Comment: @Qwertiy, я бы с радостью, но запрос именно, что бы из админки сайта все данные влетали в базу.

Comment: Ну так из админки обеспечь копирование файла в место, откуда он доступен для СУБД (если это необходимо), и выполни запрос на импорт. Чё дурью-то маяться и 2 гектара через клиентскую память прокачивать? Поди и так всё происходит в пределах одного инстанса ОС...

Comment: ну так вопрос в загрузке самого файла из админки. а кто его обрабатывает, пхп или СУБД вроде дело другое?

Comment: @teran,  - там простой шейред хостинг. Был бы хотя бы VDS - просто отправлял бы команду на прямую к СУБД.

Comment: выгрузка файла на 2гига на шаред хостинг... скорее всего это одноразовая задача и ее можно сделать из консоли. Если же нужно каждый день такое выгружать, то может делать инкрементальный cvs? и тогда задача стает простой

Comment: @KoVadim, актуализироваться база будет от 1 раза в неделю до раза в 2 месяца, как пойдёт. Что-либо менять в итоговом CSV не получится, это не зависит от меня абсолютно.

Comment: если хранить предыдущую копию файла, то можно делать обычный дифф. Он с большущей вероятностью будет небольшой. И на сервере нужно будет накатить очень немного

Answer (score 1):

Для оптимизации по памяти можно читать файл построчно и сохранять в базу каждую строку(или накапливая по 10/50/100 строк)

```php7
<?php

class CSVStreamReader
{
    /** @var resource */
    private $file;
    private string $separator;
    private string $enclosure;
    private string $escape;

    /**
     * @param resource $file
     * @param string $separator
     * @param string $enclosure
     * @param string $escape
     */
    public function __construct($file, string $separator = ",", string $enclosure = '"', string $escape = '\\')
    {
        $this->file = $file;
        $this->separator = $separator;
        $this->enclosure = $enclosure;
        $this->escape = $escape;
    }

    public function read(): Generator
    {
        while (false !== $row = fgets($this->file)) {
            yield str_getcsv($row, $this->separator, $this->enclosure, $this->escape);
        }
    }
}

$file = fopen('file.csv', 'rb');
$reader = new CSVStreamReader($file);
foreach ($reader->read() as $row) {
    //TODO save to DB, or make something useful
    print_r($row);
}
```

Не думаю что это сильно спасёт по времени, но тут можно посмотреть в сторону асинхронной обработки. То есть загружаем файл из админки, говорим пользователю что файл загружен и обрабатывается, запускаем отдельным процессом обработку файла, а пользователю показываем прогресс, и по итогу результат обработки.

альтернатива:
Если вы уверены в данных и не боитесь их загружать без валидации, то можно посмотреть в сторону https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html или поискать аналоги для вашего сервера БД

Comment: @UrinJuezz, копнул в сторону LOAD DATA, и получил другую проблему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1331892/mysql-invalid-utf8mb4-character-string