# Mysql: [Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"???? ?']

Tags: mysql, кодировка

При импорте CSV запросом:

```
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv` INTO TABLE `base` FIELDS TERMINATER...`
```

Заполучил досадную ошибку: **[Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"???? ?']**

То есть, какие-то неподдерживаемые кодировкой символы.

Попробовал перед запросом отправлять `SET NAMES utf8mb4` - без толку.

Далее, решил явно указать в запросе:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv` INTO TABLE `base` CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 FIELDS TERMINATER...
```

Всё равно. Следом уже на удачу попробовал сменить кодировки в таблице на utf8bm4 - опять без толку.

Единственное решение, которое вижу - предварительно вычищать CSV от чего попало, но есть два но:

1. Файл слишком большой, более 2 гб
2. Изначально он генерируется неизвестно каким софтом, и при ближайшем обновлении таблицы из файла всё снова начнёт валиться.

Куда стоит копать, что бы избавиться от этой штуки?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-character-set если я правильно прочитал что написано, то в запросе "LOAD DATA ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4" - нужно указывать кодировку файла, а не кодировку базы. То есть вам в запросе нужно указать кодировку cp1251. Ну, или конвертировать файл в нужный формат

Comment: @UrfinJuezz, поигравшись с разными предоставленными демо-данными, выяснил, что кодировки там всегда скачут - то cp1251, то latin1, то еще что. 
Прописал просто конвертацию в UTF-8 перед последующей записью

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пошёл по самому простому пути:

```
$file = fopen($csvFile,'r');
$out = fopen($output,'w+');

while(!feof($file)){
    $str = fgets($file, 4896);
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8', 'windows-1251');
    fwrite($out,$str);
}
```

И спокойно записываю это в БД. Долго, нудно, но пока других вариантов не нашёл.